# Why SparkSQL didn't return the normal string result?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following code to read data from parquet, then apply the SparkSQL.

```
data = sqlContext.read.parquet('hdfs://my_hdfs_path/my_db.db/my_table')
data.registerTempTable("table1")
sqlContext.sql("select id, col_A from table1").show(10)

+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id|              col_A |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
|[35 32 34 44 46 4...|[33 45 34 43 31 4...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

However, the table didn't show the normal string of column `id` and `col_A`. Instead, it was showing something like binary values. How do I make sure the result display the regular string value? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried casting the columns? `data.select(data['id'].cast('string'), data['col_A'].cast('string')).show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` has an optional parameter truncate which by default is set to `true`. If you'd like to see everything go ahead and do `show(10, truncate=false)`. DO be warned that the output won't be all nice though.

Comment: Hi, my problem is it is showing some binary like stuff, instead of the real string values. For example, the id column should be something like: "California_SanFrancisco", "California_SanJose" ... etc., however, it is showing a bunch of number instead. Any idea?

Comment: @Edamame I would suggest taking a look at how the underlying data looks like, its too organized and in nice arrays which makes me think the underlying data source could be the issue at play here.